# How to add multiple css classes to the Rich Text Editor

Tags: richtext-editor

I'm trying to add custom css class to the sitecore Rich Text editor.

```
.infinityNumber .clickable {
        background-color: #00657c;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px 0px;
    }
```

When selecting this class it only adds **clickable** class

```
<span class="clickable">test</span>
```

But I want like below. Can anyone let me know how to add like below,

```
<span class="infinityNumber clickable">test</span>
```

Comment: Hi, i think you should test this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337767/adding-multiple-css-class-to-rich-text-editor-sitecore-8

Answer (score -1):

You can add a new CSS class in the Rich Text Editor dropdown and apply it to the selected row table.

There are two steps to add CSS class in RTE:

1. Add element in `Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\ToolsFile.xml` file.
2. Now add the definition of that CSS class (eg. `arrowlink`) in `Website\default.css` file.

You can see newly added `arrowlink` CSS class in rich text editor dropdown. And apply this class wherever you want.